Trouble with an expression of expected value
So I am reading this proof about finite irreducible markov chains which says that states have unique positive stationary distribution $\pi$ such that $\pi_j=\frac{1}{\mu_j} \forall j$. The problem is not the entire proof or so, but rather one specific part of it that I don't understand. First some neccessary bits:

...
Let $Y_n$ is the number of steps from the $(n-1)$st visit to $j$ to the $n$th visit to j. By the strong markov property and by the law of large numbers
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{Y_1+Y_2+...+Y_n}{n}=\mu_j$$ with probability $1$.
Let the indicator variable $I_m$ equal $1$ if $X_m=j$ and $0$ otherwise. Then $\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}I_m$ is the number of visits to $j$ in the first steps of the chain. In the long-term:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}I_m)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}\mathbb{E}(I_m)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}P_{ij}^{m}$$.
[Now to the trouble-part]
Since there are $n$ visits to $j$ by time $Y_1+...+Y_n$, for large $n$,
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}I_m\approx\frac{n}{Y_1+...+Y_n}$$
giving that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}P_{ij}^{m}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n}{Y_1+...+Y_n}=\frac{1}{\mu_j}$$
...

So, specifically for the last equation; why is the LHS equal to the limit of $n/(Y_1+...+Y_n)$. Above we take the expectation of $1/n\sum I_m$. What happens with the expectation? Should'nt we need to also take the expectation of $n/(Y_1+...+Y_n)$ as well?

The use of the same $n$ on both sides of the "trouble" equation is spurious, as on the LHS it is counting steps of the Markov chain, and on the RHS it is counting arrivals of the chain at $j$.

Check the example 2.4.6 in Durrett's "Probability": https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf

@Wei, yes, it is very confusing.

@vanderWolf I'm not sure that is my specific problem, although I'm not sure. It is specifically handling the expectation of the approximated expression (when we let n grow) that leads to the bottom equation that I'm not following.
